# Tampermonkey script getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to use tampermonkey to delete html elements from a list on a web page, but after ~0.5s, the remaining elements get half-overwritten -

Originally: [item 1 links to item 1, item 2 links to item 2, item 3 links to item 3]

For 0.5 seconds after my script everything is perfect: [item 2 links to item 2, item 3 links to item 3]

Then the elements get overwritten (even though the hover displays correctly): [item 2 links to item 1, item 3 links to item 2]

I'm assuming this is due to some script that is running in the background, but even if I try to remove all the scripts via:

```
// @run-at document-start:
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (var k = 0; k < scripts.length; k++) {
    scripts[k].setAttribute('src', 'asdf');
    scripts[k].innerText = "";
    scripts[k].innerHTML = "";
  }
```

There is still some sort of script running in the background that is overriding the default link... Is my script override buggy/not enough? Or is there a better approach to solving this?

Comment: Are you trying to ensure that no `<script>` tags on the target page run?

Comment: As I mentioned - it's optional. I believe I have the following options:
1. prevent scripts from running after mine does
2. prevent scripts from modifying the elements I modify
3. pray removing all scripts will still load the content I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your userscript at document-start, the page may not have loaded yet - there will be no tags to remove.

If you run your userscript normally, the page will have already loaded - script tags will have likely already run.

If you want to make sure the page doesn't run any of its own scripts, attach a MutationObserver to the entire document at the beginning of pageload, and when a script tag is added, remove it. The microtask during which a MutationObserver runs will be *before* the script contents will run:

```html
<script>
// Example userscript code
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (const { addedNodes} of mutations) {
    for (addedNode of addedNodes) {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.tagName === 'SCRIPT') {
        console.log('script removed');
        addedNode.remove();
      }
    }
  }
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>

<script>
console.log('Example page script running');
</script>
<div>
  Content
  <script>
  console.log('Example nested page script running');
  </script>
</div>
```

Make sure that your userscript runs with instant script injection and `document-start`, to ensure that it runs *before* anything on the page exists. (If the page is able to get a script in before your userscript runs, it can do anything it wants)

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had to separate my scripts into 2 with this method - the document-start to strip off the javascript, and a document-end to modify what I want :)

Comment: You can use a single script by putting the rest into a DOMContentLoaded listener, if you like